# Why do I only get "OK" but not the table results when running SQL spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I want to get all incidents that occurred on 2016 April 4th from the fireIncidents table, but when I type in the following codes nothing is returned but an "OK", but when I delete the where clause the table is returned. The environment is DataBricks.

```sql
Select *
From fireIncidents
Where 'Incident Date'="04/04/2016"
```

Comment: If column name contains special characters or spaces it should be quoted using back-ticks ` not single quotes `'`. Literals, on the other hand, should use single quotes `'` not double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that Spark (as most SQL engines) actually evaluate `'Incident Date' = "04/04/2016"` to `false` sinces it compares the 2 string values. So the query will always return 0 rows. You can easily check this by :

```
spark.sql("""Select 'Incident Date'="04/04/2016"""").show()

+----------------------------+
|(Incident Date = 04/04/2016)|
+----------------------------+
|                       false|
+----------------------------+
```

You need to rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fireIncidents
WHERE   `Incident Date` = '04/04/2016'
```

Note the use of backticks **`** to escape the column name as it contains space.